# Erase empty lines from a text file in C++

Tags: c++, string, windows

I have a text file, which may contain some empty lines. I want to open this file and look for the empty lines. If an empty line exists then, I want to delete that line. ***I do not want to create a temporary file for this purpose. I want to edit the same file and close it afterwards.***

I have already seen a couple of posts about similar problem but none of them worked for me.

```
void DeleteEmptyLines(const string& FilePath)
{
    //EXISTING File
    std::fstream FileStream;
    std::string CurrentReadLine;
    if (doesFileExist(FilePath))
    {
        FileStream.open(FilePath, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

        //Read all the lines till the end of the file
        while(getline(FileStream, CurrentReadLine))
        {
            //Check if the line is empty
            if(CurrentReadLine.empty())
            {
                cout<<"Empty line found"<<endl;
                //DELETE THIS EMPTY LINE
            }
        }

        FileStream.clear();
        FileStream.close();
    }
    // else --->> do nothing
}
```

**Current File (MyFile.txt):**

```
Line1

Line2

Line3
```

**What I need (MyFile.txt):**

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

**PS:** I am using VS2010 on windows machine.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, just want to point out that with the code above you consider that lines with one or more spaces only are not empty. Is that a purpose? If the file handled is never too big, you can create the new file first in the memory, leaving out empty lines, kind of like in the example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/empty/

Comment: No, my purpose is to delete all those lines which do not have any character.

Comment: Would this work? Read everything first -> process the data -> dump the new data to file ( this time open with "w"  mode )

Comment: Isn't it possible to do the following:`Open the file in Output mode -> Read the whole file into a single string -> close the file -> open the file with all data deleted -> Delete all blanks lines from the String read in first step -> Put the string back into this file -> close the file`.

Comment: Out of interest, can you explain the rationale for not using a temporary file, as it would appear to be the most obvious solution?

Comment: @Component10 It's not just a matter of interest. It's essential to understand the problem. I can suggest some ways that are perhaps equivalent to creating a temporary file and perhaps not. Whether he'd consider them acceptable or not depends on *why* he doesn't want to create a temporary file.

Comment: I have posted an answer and it is working for me. But I think the flaw in it is that a line may contain some white spaces and then it will not be considered as an empty line. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution. Reads file into a `string` skipping empty lines, then overwrites the file with the contents of the `string`.

```
void DeleteEmptyLines(const std::string &FilePath)
{
    std::ifstream in(FilePath);
    std::string line, text;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
        if !(line.empty() || line.find_first_not_of(' ') == std::string::npos)
            text += line + "\n"
    in.close();
    std::ofstream out(FilePath);
    out << text;
}
```

**EDIT:** @skm The new answer you posted does not erase lines with empty spaces, as you stated.

To fix this use this condition to make sure a line is not "empty":

```
!(CurrentReadLine.empty() || CurrentReadLine.find_first_not_of(' ') == std::string::npos)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in all currently used filesystems, because data is stored successively. So do 'delete' some bytes from file you have to move all subsequent bytes at that amount of bytes. And you can't open file for reading and at that moment rewrite it from beginning.

So you have 3 options:

1. Read all file into memory and then rewrite lines to the original
   file skipping empty lines.
2. Read file line by line, save only
   non-empty lines into memory, and then write then down to the same file.
3. Use temporary file, which is actually a good choice because you
   don't have to have a lot of RAM and file moving operation is
   low-cost at most filesystems (if source and destination are at the
   same partition).

Comment: You can go through the file line by line, rewriting each line after the first empty one the correct number of bytes earlier in the file and then truncating it when you're done.

Comment: Coding would be more difficult, but it's possible to also rewrite the file as it's being read by rewriting only non-empty lines from the beginning while keeping track of both current read and current write locations.

Comment: @david-schwartz Doesn't it leads to some bad side-effects because of buffering when reading and so on? In memory you can do it but I'm not sure about files.

Comment: No. The stuff your reading never changes -- you're only modifying things behind the reader. But if you're worried about it, don't use any buffering.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my function as following.

```
void DeleteEmptyLines(const string& FilePath)
{
    std::string BufferString = "";

    //File
    std::fstream FileStream;
    std::string CurrentReadLine;
    if (doesFileExist(FilePath))
    {
        FileStream.open(FilePath, std::fstream::in); //open the file in Input mode

        //Read all the lines till the end of the file
        while(getline(FileStream, CurrentReadLine))
        {   
            //Check if the line is empty
            if(!CurrentReadLine.empty())
                BufferString = BufferString + CurrentReadLine + "\n";   
        }
        if(DEBUG) cout<<BufferString<<endl;
        FileStream.close();

        FileStream.open(FilePath, std::fstream::out); //open file in Output mode. This line will delete all data inside the file.
        FileStream << BufferString;
        FileStream.close();
    }
    // else --->> do nothing
}
```

This function does the following steps:

1. Open the file in input mode
2. Read all the lines which are not empty
3. Closes the file
4. Open the file again in Output mode (deletes all the data inside file)
5. Put the string into the file
6. Closes the file.